# SearchBar displaying wrong activity

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, filtering, uisearchcontroller

I have this code for my SearchBar to change my collection view :

```
extension ProductsCollectionViewController : UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating
{
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        let searchString = productsSearchController.searchBar.text

        filtered = products.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
            let prodName: NSString = (item as Product).Name() as NSString

            return (prodName.range(of: searchString!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
        })

        ProductsCollection.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchActive = true
        ProductsCollection.reloadData()
    }


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchActive = false
        ProductsCollection.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        LoadProducts(productsToShow: latestLoadedProducts)
        ProductsCollection.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        if !searchActive
        {
            searchActive = true
            ProductsCollection.reloadData()
        }

        productsSearchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

extension ProductsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate
{

}

extension ProductsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource
{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if searchActive
        {
            return filtered.count
        }
        else
        {
            return products.count    //return number of rows in section
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "product_collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductsCollectionViewCell

        let prodInCell = products[indexPath.row]
        let imgUrl = prodInCell.GetMainImageURLString()

        if imgUrl == nil || imgUrl == "" // MARK - make sure no "" is used, only nil
        {
            // No main image exists
            cell.ProductImageView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultProductImage")
        }
        else
        {
            // Main Image exists
            let url = URL(string: imgUrl)
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            {
                cell.ProductImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }

        // Set fields

        cell.ProductName.text = prodInCell.Name()
        cell.ProductPrice.text = String(prodInCell.Price())
        cell.productUniqueID = prodInCell.UniqueID()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Display selected Item
        prodToLoad = products[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "view_product_information", sender:self  )
    }

}
```

I want to filter items by their name. Product is a custom NSObject I made with "name" as a property. When I am searching for an item, wrong information is shown:

[image: Search result]

1. When I am searching for "A" - wrong results are shown. How do I fix that ?
2. When I click the "X"/Cancel button - I want my original view to be shown. Is there a way to make this happen without cloning the original array of products ?
3. When I first click on the search button - all products disappear. How do I prevent this from happening ? I want all products to be shown when search string is empty.

Comment: okay, so.. where are your _collection-view-delegate_ and _collection-view-datasource-delegate_ implementations?

Comment: Added to post :)

Comment: how about taking a closer look at this line: `let prodInCell = products[indexPath.row]` in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method, and sit down for a sec then think about what that line actually does here...?

Comment: Extracts the relevant product so I can get information from it. What am I missing ?

Comment: okay, I give you another hint: what kinda product information will that single line return to you? the _filtered_ products or the _original_ products?

Comment: after trying to search for something ? Since products.filter is called, I believe it will extract the filtered products information

Comment: okay, I give you one more direct hint: the `filtered` variable contains the _filtered_ array, the `products` array still contains the _original_ list of items... and that is pretty much the solution to your problem in one go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166251/discussion-between-ofri-and-holex).

Comment: oh, geez... just replace the referred line with this line: `let prodInCell = searchActive ? filtered[indexPath.row] : products[indexPath.row]`, there is nothing more to talk about that :)

Comment: Thanks, That's 1+2 answered.

Comment: if you don't want your products disappear, then you should make `filtered = products` when the search term's length is `0`, shall I create an answer for you?

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code and it worked. Do you want to add an official solution so that I can credit you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Q.1

> When I am searching for "A" - wrong results are shown. How do I fix that ?

## A.1

basically the answer is quite simple to that questions, you just need to take a look on the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` implementation and replacing this line:

```
let prodInCell = products[indexPath.row]
```

with this:

```
let prodInCell = searchActive ? filtered[indexPath.row] : products[indexPath.row]
```

#### why?

you have the *filtered* array in your `filtered` variable, so you need to grab the record from that as well during the search; whilst the `products` array contains the original list of items intact whole time.

---

## Q.2

> When I click the "X"/Cancel button - I want my original view to be shown. Is there a way to make this happen without cloning the original array of products?

## A.2

you. can get back the original list when you add something like that to inside the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_:)` method before you reload the data:

```
searchActive = false
```

#### why?

in your implementation that ends the search and when you reload all data, it will be loaded from the `products` array when the `searchActive` value is false.

---

## Q.3

> When I first click on the search button - all products disappear. How do I prevent this from happening ? I want all products to be shown when search string is empty.

## A.3

inside the update `updateSearchResults(for:)` method you need to check whether the search term's length is `0`, if yes, you just make sure the `filtered = product`, something like that:

```
filtered = searchString.count = 0 ? products : products.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
    // do whatever you just do already
})
```

#### why?

because that makes the *filtered* list identical to list of all products initially.